# Setting arbitrary cursor positions with multiple cursors in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to modify different parts of my file with the same string. So I installed [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) in emacs. But unfortunately, I cannot do the (simple?) thing of marking different parts of the text and start to edit.

Each command I have checked seems not useful to do what I want. For instance consider I need to edit the beginning of line 10 and a character in the middle of line 34. How do I do that?

Comment: See also https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/44 and https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/265

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the command `mc/add-cursor-on-click`, which I personally have bound to `C-S-<mouse-1>`. With this setup, I can hold `Ctrl` and `Shift` and click the beginning of line 10, and then click the middle of line 34, and I will have a cursor in both positions.

You can bind this command the way I have like this in your init:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)
```

You can replace the `kbd` with another combination too if you want.

Comment: n.b. That's actually an alias for `mc/toggle-cursor-on-click` -- which is a more descriptive name for what it does.

Comment: @phils good to know, thanks! The command I reference is the one Magnars uses in the readme for multiple cursors, and I just copied it from there when I started using the package. I didn't realize it toggled actually, but will experiment with it now. I rarely use the mouse for this anyway, but sometimes (like in the situation in OPs question, it can really come in handy.

Comment: I expect the toggling functionality came at some later point, and the original name was retained (in alias form) for backwards-compatibility. ([Yep](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/commit/40eb74e3e44aa72948db92dc58a8769153fd83f3)).

Answer (score 2):

The following is derived from https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/44 and seems like a reasonable keyboard-driven solution.

```el
(require 'multiple-cursors)

(defun mc/toggle-cursor-at-point ()
  "Add or remove a cursor at point."
  (interactive)
  (if multiple-cursors-mode
      (message "Cannot toggle cursor at point while `multiple-cursors-mode' is active.")
    (let ((existing (mc/fake-cursor-at-point)))
      (if existing
          (mc/remove-fake-cursor existing)
        (mc/create-fake-cursor-at-point)))))

(add-to-list 'mc/cmds-to-run-once 'mc/toggle-cursor-at-point)
(add-to-list 'mc/cmds-to-run-once 'multiple-cursors-mode)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-SPC") 'mc/toggle-cursor-at-point)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-return>") 'multiple-cursors-mode)
```

Firstly use `mc/toggle-cursor-at-point` to mark each position where you want a cursor, and then invoke `multiple-cursors-mode` to activate them.